# How to remove everything except a specific word in C#

Tags: c#

I want to remove specific value from a variable. For example, If I have a variable value as **&MASTER&DYN,PHA/12345/12/56**, I want to remove everything except the value **&MASTER&** i.e. value **DYN,PHA/12345/12/56** to be removed. I tried with using .Remove() function, but was not successful.

Comment: `string val = "&MASTER&";`

Comment: You should at least show what you have tried and tell us why you think that it didn't work

Comment: Remove creates a __new__ string!!!!

Comment: I am really sorry for asking such a stupid question

Comment: @Yash It's OK - We have all been there...

Answer (score 8):

why just not to assign needed value?

```
if (s.Contains("&MASTER&")) s = "&MASTER&";
```